# React-router v4 silently change url while using endless scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, endlessscroll

I have an article read page, which I can enter by using url like '/article/id'. In this article read I have endless scroll, which is uploading new articles when you scroll far down, and I want to change my url to currently viewed article url without doing any rerendering or something. Just change url and nothing more. I've tried `this.props.history.push();`, but this solution doesn't seem like a success.